# C# code to perform Binary search in a very big text file

Tags: c#, file-io, binary-search

Is there a library that I can use to perform binary search in a very big text file (can be 10GB).

The file is a sort of a log file - every row starts with a date and time. Therefore rows are ordered.

Comment: Are you searching for a date and time or something else in the file?

Comment: I am searching by date and time. The fact that the file is ordered by date and time is what makes binary search possible in the first place.
I want to find the position of the row in the file, or the row itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started to write the pseudo-code on how to do it, but I gave up since it may seem condescending. You probably know how to write a binary search, it's really not complicated.

You won't find it in a library, for two reasons:

1. It's not really "binary search" - the line sizes are different, so  you need to adapt the algorithm (e.g. look for the middle of the file, then look for the next "newline" and consider that to be the "middle").
2. Your datetime log format is most likely non-standard (ok, it may look "standard", but think a bit.... you probably use '[]' or something to separate the date from the log message, something like [10/02/2001 10:35:02] My message ).

On summary - I think your need is too specific and too simple to implement in custom code for someone to bother writing a library :)

Answer (score 4):

As the line lengths are not guaranteed to be the same length, you're going to need some form of recognisable line delimiter e.g. carriage return or line feed.

The binary search pattern can then be pretty much your traditional algorithm. Seek to the 'middle' of the file (by length), seek backwards (byte by byte) to the start of the line you happen to land in, as identified by the line delimiter sequence, read that record and make your comparison. Depending on the comparison, seek halfway up or down (in bytes) and repeat.

When you identify the start index of a record, check whether it was the same as the last seek. You may find that, as you dial in on your target record, moving halfway won't get you to a different record. e.g. you have adjacent records of 100 bytes and 50 bytes respectively, so jumping in at 75 bytes always takes you back to the start of the first record. If that happens, read on to the next record before making your comparison.

You should find that you will reach your target pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too bad under the constraint that you hold an Int64 in memory for every line-feed in the file.  That really depends upon how long the line of text is on average, given 1000 bytes per line you be looking at around (10,000,000,000 / 1000 * 4) = 40mb. Very big, but possible.

So try this:

1. Scan the file and store the ordinal offset of each line-feed in a List
2. Binary search the List with a custom comparer that scans to the file offset and reads the data.

Comment: If your going to be performing the search only a few times then I'd go with Neil Moss's answer, If you going to do the search a lot or are uncomfortable writing a binary search, use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is static (or changes rarely) and you have to run "enough" queries against it, I believe the best approach will be creating "index" file:

1. Scan the initial file and take the datetime parts of the file plus their positions in the original (this is why has to be pretty static) encode them some how (for example: unix time (full 10 digits) + nanoseconds (zero-filled 4 digits) and line position (zero filed 10 digits). this way you will have file with consistent "lines"
2. preform binary search on that file (you may need to be a bit creative in order to achieve range search) and get the relevant location(s) in the original file
3. read directly from the original file starting from the given location / read the given range

You've got range search with O(log(n)) run-time :) (and you've created primitive DB functionality)

Needless to say that if the file data file is updated "too" frequently or you don't run "enough" queries against the index file you mat end up with spending more time on creating the index file than you are saving from the query file.

Btw, working with this index file doesn't require the data file to be sorted. As log files tend to be append only, and sorted, you may speed up the whole thing by simply creating index file that only holds the locations of the EOL marks (zero-filled 10 digits)  in the data file - this way you can preform the binary search directly on the data-file (using the index file in order to determinate the seek positions in the original file) and if lines are appended to the log file you can simply add  (append) their EOL positions to the index file.

Answer (score -2):

The List object has a Binary Search method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: This would require him to load the entire file into a list of lines.  The file size prohibits this.

Comment: And how in gods name should he load a 10GB file in memory?

Comment: @Jason Punyon, @Steven -- Yeah, if you're excessively stupid and you plan on loading the entire thing into a single list, yes.  Did I say that?  No.  I was just giving a starting spot.  Go troll someone else.